# Use drawable and <shape> in <item> XML

Tags: android

Is it possible to use a XML-Background ressource with an drawable and a `<shape>` attribute?

So I have this button

```
        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button" />
```

Which has a background send_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp"/>

</selector>
```

This works fine right now. But I also want to add a background-color behind the drawable and rounded corners like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#88b823"
        android:startColor="#b0dc54" />

</shape>
```

So is it possible to combine these two XML ressources?
What I've tried so far, just displays the drawable and not the shape:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />

            <gradient android:angle="270" 
                android:endColor="#88b823" 
                android:startColor="#b0dc54" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Try combining the bitmap and the shape into a [layer drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), then use that as the background.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. Could you please post this as an answer, so I can accept ist. I have a `<layer-list>` with two `<item>`-attributes, in the first comes the `<shape>` and the second one holds the `<bitmap>`.

Comment: Actually, why don't you answer your own question, so you can provide more of the code that you used. That'll be more useful to people seeing this question in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for pointing me in the right direction. This is the working code (currently only for the default state):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_send_white_48dp" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/action_bar" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Works on my end. Thank you!